# Prevent the .git directory from being server by NGINX

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to prevent nginx from serving the .git directory. I've tried a
number of suggested things from this site, e.g:

```
    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
             deny all;
             access_log off;
             log_not_found off;
    }
    location ~ /\.(.*)/?(.*)? {
             deny all;
             return 404;
    }

   location ~ /\.git {
            deny all;
    }
```

But all of these still allow nginx to serve the config file within the .git directory. A https request to server-name/.git/config is still successful.

The output of `nginx -T`:

```
 server {
     server_name umami.server-name.ch;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/umami.server-name.ch/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/umami.server-name.ch/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}



server {
    if ($host = umami.server-name.ch) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name umami.server-name.ch;
#    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}

# configuration file /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf:
# This file contains important security parameters. If you modify this file
# manually, Certbot will be unable to automatically provide future security
# updates. Instead, Certbot will print and log an error message with a path to
# the up-to-date file that you will need to refer to when manually updating
# this file. Contents are based on https://ssl-config.mozilla.org

ssl_session_cache shared:le_nginx_SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout 1440m;
ssl_session_tickets off;

ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384";

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/www.server-name.ch:
# You may add here your
# server {
#   ...
# }
# statements for each of your virtual hosts to this file

##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

server {

    root /var/www/www.server-name.ch/;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name www.server-name.ch server-name.ch;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules

    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

                # With php5-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;

        # With php5-fpm:
        # fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        # fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        #fastcgi_index index.php;
        #include fastcgi_params;
        #include fastcgi.conf;
    }

        location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
                 deny all;
                 access_log off;
                 log_not_found off;
        }
        location ~ /\.(.*)/?(.*)? {
         deny all;
                 return 404;
        }

       location ~ /\.git {
                deny all;
        }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.server-name.ch/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.server-name.ch/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}


server {
   if ($host = www.server-name.ch) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = server-name.ch) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    server_name www.server-name.ch server-name.ch;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
    if ($http_user_agent ~ (libwww|Wget|LWP|damnBot|BBBike|java|spider|crawl) ) {
       return 403;
   }
}

}
```

Comment: Please add your full nginx configuration as shown by `nginx -T` to the question.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen, thanks, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line with `~ /\.git` should be `~ /\.git.*` such that is matches to everything coming after.